Why is one of two nearly identical MySQL views so slow?
I've been investigating an issue with one of our application queries running very slowly and it seems to be related to a particular view we're using.
Here is the full query with the selected columns omitted (there are 408 columns being selected)
SELECT `skus`.`yom_sku`
-- omitted columns (408)
FROM   `skus`
       LEFT JOIN `product_families_view`
              ON `product_families_view`.`product_id` = `skus`.`yom_sku`
       LEFT JOIN `product_profit_projection_view`
              ON `product_profit_projection_view`.`product_id` =
                 `skus`.`yom_sku`
       LEFT JOIN `product_media_types_view`
              ON `product_media_types_view`.`product_id` = `skus`.`yom_sku`
       LEFT JOIN `product`
              ON `product`.`yom_sku` = `skus`.`yom_sku`
       LEFT JOIN `product_listings`
              ON `product_listings`.`asin` = `skus`.`asin`
                 AND `product_listings`.`seller_sku` = `skus`.`upc`
       LEFT JOIN `analyst`
              ON `analyst`.`yom_sku` = `skus`.`yom_sku`
       LEFT JOIN `collection`
              ON `collection`.`yom_sku` = `skus`.`yom_sku`
       LEFT JOIN `supplier_pricing`
              ON `supplier_pricing`.`yom_sku` = `skus`.`yom_sku`
       LEFT JOIN `amazon_order`
              ON `amazon_order`.`yom_sku` = `skus`.`yom_sku`
       LEFT JOIN `amazon_pricing`
              ON `amazon_pricing`.`yom_sku` = `skus`.`yom_sku`
WHERE  `product`.`retired` = false
ORDER  BY `skus`.`upc` ASC
LIMIT  100  

The query is quite large, but one view in particular (the 'product_media_types_view') is taking a significant amount of read resources for some reason. This is particularly odd because it's nearly identical in structure to another view called "product_families_view" and there are no apparent indexing issues.
Here are the two views for comparison:
-- pricetooldb.product_families_view source

CREATE OR REPLACE
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED VIEW `pricetooldb`.`product_families_view` AS
select
    `pfp`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `pfp`.`part_number` AS `part_number`,
    group_concat(`pf`.`family` order by `pf`.`family` ASC separator ', ') AS `families`
from
    (`pricetooldb`.`product_families` `pf`
join `pricetooldb`.`product_families_products` `pfp` on
    ((`pfp`.`family_id` = `pf`.`id`)))
group by
    `pfp`.`product_id`;

-- pricetooldb.product_media_types_view source

CREATE OR REPLACE
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED VIEW `pricetooldb`.`product_media_types_view` AS
select
    `pmt`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    group_concat(`mt`.`name` order by `mt`.`name` ASC separator ' ') AS `media_types`
from
    (`pricetooldb`.`media_types` `mt`
join `pricetooldb`.`product_media_types` `pmt` on
    ((`pmt`.`media_type_id` = `mt`.`id`)))
group by
    `pmt`.`product_id`;

I've run EXPLAIN EXTENDED on the problem SQL query above and found the product_media_types_view takes significantly more resources than the highly similar product_families_view
[
  {
    "table": {
      "table_name": "product_families_view",
      "access_type": "ref",
      "possible_keys": [
        "<auto_key0>"
      ],
      "key": "<auto_key0>",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "product_id"
      ],
      "key_length": "4",
      "ref": [
        "pricetooldb.skus.yom_sku"
      ],
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 10,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 75142,
      "filtered": "100.00",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "45073.14",
        "eval_cost": "15028.53",
        "prefix_cost": "165159.79",
        "data_read_per_join": "4M"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "product_id",
        "part_number",
        "families"
      ],
      "materialized_from_subquery": {
        "using_temporary_table": true,
        "dependent": false,
        "cacheable": true,
        "query_block": {
          "select_id": 2,
          "cost_info": {
            "query_cost": "48405.37"
          },
          "grouping_operation": {
            "using_temporary_table": true,
            "using_filesort": true,
            "cost_info": {
              "sort_cost": "21756.26"
            },
            "nested_loop": [
              {
                "table": {
                  "table_name": "pf",
                  "access_type": "index",
                  "possible_keys": [
                    "PRIMARY"
                  ],
                  "key": "product_families_family_unique",
                  "used_key_parts": [
                    "family"
                  ],
                  "key_length": "257",
                  "rows_examined_per_scan": 2653,
                  "rows_produced_per_join": 2653,
                  "filtered": "100.00",
                  "using_index": true,
                  "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "11.00",
                    "eval_cost": "530.60",
                    "prefix_cost": "541.60",
                    "data_read_per_join": "683K"
                  },
                  "used_columns": [
                    "id",
                    "family"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "table": {
                  "table_name": "pfp",
                  "access_type": "ref",
                  "possible_keys": [
                    "product_entry_unique",
                    "product_families_products_family_id_foreign"
                  ],
                  "key": "product_families_products_family_id_foreign",
                  "used_key_parts": [
                    "family_id"
                  ],
                  "key_length": "4",
                  "ref": [
                    "pricetooldb.pf.id"
                  ],
                  "rows_examined_per_scan": 8,
                  "rows_produced_per_join": 21756,
                  "filtered": "100.00",
                  "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "21756.26",
                    "eval_cost": "4351.25",
                    "prefix_cost": "26649.11",
                    "data_read_per_join": "1M"
                  },
                  "used_columns": [
                    "id",
                    "product_id",
                    "family_id",
                    "part_number"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "table": {
      "table_name": "product_media_types_view",
      "access_type": "ref",
      "possible_keys": [
        "<auto_key0>"
      ],
      "key": "<auto_key0>",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "product_id"
      ],
      "key_length": "4",
      "ref": [
        "pricetooldb.skus.yom_sku"
      ],
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 10,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 1214678,
      "filtered": "100.00",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "728729.15",
        "eval_cost": "242935.67",
        "prefix_cost": "1321922.89",
        "data_read_per_join": "27M"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "product_id",
        "media_types"
      ],
      "materialized_from_subquery": {
        "using_temporary_table": true,
        "dependent": false,
        "cacheable": true,
        "query_block": {
          "select_id": 5,
          "cost_info": {
            "query_cost": "122384.12"
          },
          "grouping_operation": {
            "using_filesort": false,
            "nested_loop": [
              {
                "table": {
                  "table_name": "p",
                  "access_type": "index",
                  "possible_keys": [
                    "PRIMARY"
                  ],
                  "key": "PRIMARY",
                  "used_key_parts": [
                    "yom_sku"
                  ],
                  "key_length": "4",
                  "rows_examined_per_scan": 46669,
                  "rows_produced_per_join": 46669,
                  "filtered": "100.00",
                  "using_index": true,
                  "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "867.00",
                    "eval_cost": "9333.80",
                    "prefix_cost": "10200.80",
                    "data_read_per_join": "74M"
                  },
                  "used_columns": [
                    "yom_sku"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "table": {
                  "table_name": "pmt",
                  "access_type": "ref",
                  "possible_keys": [
                    "product_media_types_product_id_media_type_id_unique"
                  ],
                  "key": "product_media_types_product_id_media_type_id_unique",
                  "used_key_parts": [
                    "product_id"
                  ],
                  "key_length": "5",
                  "ref": [
                    "pricetooldb.p.yom_sku"
                  ],
                  "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
                  "rows_produced_per_join": 46795,
                  "filtered": "100.00",
                  "using_index": true,
                  "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "46669.22",
                    "eval_cost": "9359.16",
                    "prefix_cost": "66229.17",
                    "data_read_per_join": "731K"
                  },
                  "used_columns": [
                    "id",
                    "product_id",
                    "media_type_id"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "table": {
                  "table_name": "mt",
                  "access_type": "eq_ref",
                  "possible_keys": [
                    "PRIMARY"
                  ],
                  "key": "PRIMARY",
                  "used_key_parts": [
                    "id"
                  ],
                  "key_length": "4",
                  "ref": [
                    "pricetooldb.pmt.media_type_id"
                  ],
                  "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
                  "rows_produced_per_join": 46795,
                  "filtered": "100.00",
                  "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "46795.79",
                    "eval_cost": "9359.16",
                    "prefix_cost": "122384.12",
                    "data_read_per_join": "731K"
                  },
                  "used_columns": [
                    "id",
                    "name"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

It isn't clear to me why. I'll provide the 'product', 'product_media_types', and 'media_types' DDLs below (with irrelevant columns from 'product' redacted)
-- pricetooldb.product definition

CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `yom_sku` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`yom_sku`),
  CONSTRAINT `yom_sku_prod_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`yom_sku`) REFERENCES `skus` (`yom_sku`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- pricetooldb.product_media_types definition

CREATE TABLE `product_media_types` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_type_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_media_types_product_id_media_type_id_unique` (`product_id`,`media_type_id`),
  KEY `product_media_types_media_type_id_foreign` (`media_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_media_types_media_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`media_type_id`) REFERENCES `media_types` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `product_media_types_product_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`yom_sku`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46247 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- pricetooldb.media_types definition

CREATE TABLE `media_types` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or ideas about why the "product_media_types_view" is so expensive.

Provide plans in tabular form, JSON is unreadable.\

Ah thank you, that is better. I've updated the post to include the full EXPLAIN statement in tabular form, though it does include less information than the JSON format. Let me know if any additional info helps @Akina

Nothing identical on those two views. They run on different tables.

And MySQL 5.7 is obsolete at this point. TIme to upgrade.

@TheImpaler The underlying tables and the views themselves are nearly identical in structure. "media_types" and "product_families" are associated with products via link tables. The views just GROUP_CONCAT these many-to-many associations, hence they are nearly the same.
Oddly, the link tables have roughly the same amount of data. I have no idea why MySQL is having trouble with the media_type view. It doesn't seem like an index problem..

The EXPLAIN shows significantly different table references than I see in the view definitions, or in the first JSON-format EXPLAIN you posted. Are some of the tables referenced by your views also views?

When asking [tag:query-optimization] questions, please include the table definition DDL (SHOW CREATE TABLE) for each table referenced by the query. This helps us if we want to test your query, or if we want to understand the data types, indexes, and constraints you currently have. Help us to help you!

@BillKarwin Hey thanks for the tip Bill, I've edited the post to try and improve clarity and provide the DDLs. I took a look and none of the views reference other views

You're still missing DDL for most of the tables referenced by your query. I've lost interest in helping. Good luck!

@kliuyyyy FIRST action, ANALYZE each table used in the troubled view to correct any possible index corruption.  Check your timings after EACH ANALYZE is completed and you could be certain which table's indexes were corrupted. SECOND action, review this URL - https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_left.asp  and consider the table1 and table2 references in their documentation.  Yours seem to be mostly reversed in their order of usage.

Turns out the issue was unrelated to that particular view. I'm not sure why but the MySQL 5.7 analyzer may simply have weird behavior with where it estimates the majority of its costs are coming from. Querying the two views directly shows that the "product_media_types_view" is actually faster.
I added a few indexes to other tables and the query has been sped up fairly significantly.
